# Why the function empty seems to empty the result?

Tags: php, is-empty

I have a weird result in PHP.

```
if( $mandatory_param === "name" ){
    var_dump( $data );
    exit();
}

//output : array(6) { ["name"]=> string(4) "plan" ["class"]=> string(33) "Path\Plan" ["dbtable"]=> string(5) "plans" ["getter"]=> string(7) "plan_id" ["editable"]=> string(4) "true" ["slug"]=> string(2) "pl" }
```

But when I try the `empty` function to test the array, the result change even if the first output show this : `["name"]=> string(4) "plan"`

```
if( $mandatory_param === "name" && empty( $data[ $mandatory_param ] ) ){
  var_dump( $data );
  exit();
}

//Output : array(0) { }
```

Why ? The `empty()` function seems to empty my array not to check if it´s empty.

Comment: $mandatory_param is a simple variable or array ...?

Comment: $mandatory_param is a simple variable which contains only the string. I have just check it.

Comment: My program needs to detect if the mandatories parameter are empty or not. And for the case of 'name', I have this weird result.

Comment: This question will marked as low quality. Please provide more information about `$mandatory_param` and `$data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the complete code it's impossible to say for sure, but to make an educated guess:

When you don't have the `empty()` check, the `exit()` is triggered the first time you call the piece of code / function, and `$data` is set.

When you add `empty`, the previous call that ended up inside the if-statement does not do so any longer (since `name` is set for that array), and thus, doesn't produce any output or a call to `exit`(so the code keeps running).

The code then runs until the test is performed with an array that doesn't have `$data['name']` set, performs a `var_dump` (on what is now an empty array) and exits.

Your call to empty does not remove anything, you're just dumping a  different set of data later in your application's run.

Comment: Do you think it´s because this code is inside a method of a trait that I use for several objects ?

Comment: It's because the code is being called multiple times, and when you `exit()` the first time, you're calling it with different parameters than when it calls `exit()` in your second example. In the first case it never reaches the code that triggers the valid `empty` check, as it exists regardless of whether `$data['name']` is present.